# Unable to post new review

Tags: review, ce-1.9.2.4

I have a Magento environment that runs on Magento 1.9.2.4 and I'm trying to submit a review. The review however doesn't show up in the list of pending (or all) reviews. I'm using the base so it should work fine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you allow review in backoffice. **System > Configuration > Catalog > Review** (in case where you are not logged)

Comment: This was already set to yes.

Comment: Have you got the right configuration scope selected?